# Open Windows Explorer find pane with a search term

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command, find, explorer

I am trying to create an application which opens the Windows Explorer search function and searches for files/folders with the specified term entered. I have the code already for Windows Vista SP1+ (which uses the "search:query=") command introduced with Windows Indexing service. This does not work in Windows XP and so I am in search of a command/code (command line, batch script, c++, etc) that will open Windows Explorer in the "find file/folder" mode with the search term entered also (send from the application with the command). Thanks

Comment: An option might be to simply use SendKeys; not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a (really long) command that can do a search.

```
explorer.exe search-ms:displayname=Search Results (or put whatever title you want)&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A(search string)&crumb=location:(path)
```

Here's a breakdown of how it works:

If you run `explorer.exe path`, it will open the path you specify.
If you do a search and click on the icon used to show a path, it will show you a really long string of data.  You can enter it as a path, and it will take you right back to the search.
In case you haven't figured it out, you can enter a command to take you to that path, therefore running a search.

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows 8.1, where do you observe this working?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working in Windows 10 either.

Comment: It was working when I tried it, but it was a long time ago and I'm no longer using Windows.  You can probably figure out the new path by starting a search, pressing CTRL + L and adapting the content of the text.  It also may be that I forgot to put quotes around the command.

Answer (score 0):

With credit to,

http://www.somethingtoscrollthrough.com/2020/07/command-line-search-ms.html

for giving me the correct syntax, the following opens an Explorer Window on Windows 10 in search mode with the query,

PDF documents on D drive whose text contents contain **ALL** the words (Windows, macro, openoffice).

`explorer.exe "search-ms:query=content:(Windows AND macro AND openoffice) name:.pdf&crumb=location:d:\&"`

[image]

For an exact phrase, use this form (note the double double quotes `""`),

`explorer.exe "search-ms:query=content:""OOME Fourth Edition"" name:.pdf&crumb=location:d:\&"`

Or at its most basic form, all PDF files on Drive D that start with A,

`explorer.exe "search-ms:query=a*.pdf&crumb=location:d:\&"`

For more ideas of what is possible consult MS' syntax reference here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference