# Open Windows Explorer and perform a search

Tags: c#, process, explorer

If we want to open Windows Explorer and select a file, we can use the command

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," + @"c:\Folder\file.txt");
```

Is there a way to open Windows Explorer programmatically and show the results of a search? For example, as a user I can open Windows Explorer and fill in "*.txt" into search area to list all text files.

Comment: There's a comment here saying this command doesn't work on Windows 8.1 can you try it on Windows 10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49763747/495455

Comment: Thanks, I had a look and it doesn't work in Windows 10. I can copy the link with the search results and I can paste it into a new Explorer window and it will work. But if I try to execute it from console or using Process.Start() it didn't work. Maybe there is some tweaking needed.

Comment: I have this gut feeling something has changed, for example in 8.1 SendKeys worked but not in 10's implementation. Microsoft are forever worried about people hijacking explorer and office apps. I wonder if there is another way, maybe try ProcessMonitor while entering a search and see if uses any RegKeys or see here how you can save folders with searches: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2163343&seqNum=17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. It was in fact very simple. Assume I am searching for files with filename containing the term "mat" in folder "C:\temp1". The explorer window has the title "CustomSearch". It works in Windows 10.

```
string searchLink = "search-ms:displayname=CustomSearch&crumb=filename%3A*mat%20&crumb=location:C%3A%5Ctemp1";
Process.Start(searchLink);
```

Comment: Does not work in Windows 11 :-(